# Cannot resolve unit name 'DBTables' at line 20 (BDE)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm facing up a problem to run my program. My code is so old that I'm not sure how it works.

```
Cannot resolve unit name 'DBTables' at line 20
Underclared indetifier 'EDBEnginerError'
Underclared identifier 'Error'
```

I think it is missing BDE, but how do I Import it to my project?

Things that I already tried:
 - Migrate BDE to FireDac with no success. These classes were not replaced.

Comment: You aren't going to make progress until you engage with your code. Start by compiling it in its original environment.

Comment: "Migrate BDE to FireDac" - How exactly did you do so? The classes don't get automatically replaced. "migrating" means completely modifying every place in your code to use FireDac components instead of BDE components. Not just pointing it to a different unit. The hardest part should be changing the connection component to use specific properties instead of a single connection string or DSN references, etc. PS: BDE has been deprecated since the year 2000.

Comment: @Jerry, _don't get automatically replaced_ - well, can be by the reFind tool using the included regex patterns.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Yes, re-doing connections could be bothersome, esp with the TDatabase abomination.  Personally, though, as FireDAC's author has left (or been l"let go" by) EMBA, it might be wise to steer well clear of it.  It'll be interesting to see how Idera's contractors get on with keeping it maintained.  If indeed they do.  ADO seems a much safer bet to me.

Comment: You can use the [shipped importer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/BDE_Aliases_Migration_(FireDAC)).

Answer (score 7):

BDE is deprecated. Recent versions of Delphi do not install BDE support files by default.  See:

[BDE Installer for RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30752)

[BDE components in RAD Studio/Delphi/C++ Builder](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/44082)

Installing the BDE, should allow the compiler to find DBTables.Pas.  That should fix the undeclared identifier errors.

That should get you going, but if you are needing to do any development work, you should really consider replacing the BDE.

Initially Delphi's DB support, in 1995, was based on the BDE, which was Borland's attempt to do similar to MS's ODBC.  As a result, many later DB libraries, like FireDAC include TxQuery and TxTable components that work similarly to TTable and TQuery, so upgrading a straightforward BDE-based app to a more modern DB-access library needn't be too painful,  **unless** the BDE app made extensive use of direct calls to the BDE query engine - those calls usually are prefixed `dbi`.  If your code has lots of those, you are in for an `interesting` time upgrading.

Comment: Since I have a trial account I cannot download anything by Embarcadero. I have plans to replace BDE, of course. First of all I just wanted to build my environment with BDE to see how painfully it would be. Now I'm lost. :(

Comment: See the bit I've added to my answer, which may give you a clue whether it's worth getting a paid-for version.  OR, you could consider using FPC+ Lazarus.

Comment: FireDAC includes regex patterns for the reFind tool for automated migration (follow [Migrating BDE Applications to FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Migrating_BDE_Applications_to_FireDAC) topic).

Answer (score 0):

Even though the BDE has been deprecated for years, that does not mean that it no longer works. Even the latest version Delphi 10.2 ships with the units Bde.DBTables:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Bde.DBTables
It may not be part of the trial version though.

In addition you will need the BDE itself which no longer ships with Delphi but can still be downloaded from Embarcadero. (Actually I am not sure, it might even still be an optional part in the Delphi Installer.)

Comment: I installed 10.2 trial Architect edition, then purchased 10.3 Enterprise edition.  BDE was not offered as an option in the installation process for either.  As you pointed out, though, it is available as a downloaded add-on.