# Delphi 10.2 - Cannot resolve unit name 'DBExpress' at line 6 (DBExpress)

Tags: delphi, resolve, dbexpress

```
unit uDataModule;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DBExpress, DB, DBClient, SimpleDS, SqlExpr, FMTBcd,
  ADODB, Data.DBXInterBase, Data.DBXOracle;
```

I'm trying to compile a project made in an old version of Delphi into Delphi 10.2 IDE. But having this problem with this declaration.

Comment: You should put the exact error message in the text of the question with an [edit]. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44314923/1531971

Comment: @jdv: The post you linked has nothing to do with DBExpress. It's BDE-related, and DBExpress isn't from the BDE.

Comment: Delphi 10.2 does not include a unit named `DBExpress`. What specific components do you use that would be from that unit? What happens if you comment it out or remove it? If I open a new VCL project in Tokyo 10.2.2 (Pro SKU) and drop every single component from the DBExpress tab on it and compile, it does not add DBExpress to the uses clause anywhere. What happens if you do the same in a new, blank VCL application?

Comment: *"The dbExpress unit is deprecated, is empty, and consequently no longer needed. Most of this unit's content has been moved to either the DBXCommon or SQLExpr units."* - from D2007 readme.